Apply custom product attribute filter directly in layered navigation
I have one text custom attribute for product. I want to apply directly in Category/Search page and also in Layered Navigation.
I have tried by override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer this file but by this filter applied in product listing but not applied in layered navigation.
Can anyone has idea about it?

we cannot get the custom product attribute in Layered navigation for type text field, it will work for dropdown, multiselect, yes/not attribute types.

share your custom product attribute patch file. and how are you trying to implement it?

I used a Plugin for Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection with a beforeLoad method.
The problem I face now is that the product count shown in the Leyered navigation does not correspond with the filtered products.
   public function beforeLoad(Collection $subject)
    {
        $subject->addAttributeToFilter('attribute', ['eq' => self::VALUE]);

        return null;
    }


To add a custom attribute to the layered navigation in Magento 2, you need to ensure that the attribute is set up correctly and that the necessary changes are made to the layout and templates. Here's a step-by-step guide:
Step 1: Ensure the Custom Attribute is Configured Correctly

Log in to the Magento Admin Panel.
Go to Stores > Attributes > Product.
Find your custom attribute and edit it.
Ensure the following settings are configured correctly:

Use in Layered Navigation: Set to "Filterable (with results)" or "Filterable (no results)".
Use in Search Results Layered Navigation: Set to "Yes".
Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront: Set to "Yes".



Step 2: Update the Product Listing

Override the Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer class.
Add your custom logic to filter products by the custom attribute.

Step 3: Add the Attribute to Layered Navigation

Override the Layered Navigation template and block.
Create a custom module if you haven't already, e.g., Vendor/Module.
Override the necessary files:

Block Override
Create or edit the block to add the custom attribute to the filter options.
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\LayeredNavigation;

class Filter extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter
{
    protected function _prepareFilter()
    {
        // Add custom logic to prepare the filter based on the custom attribute
    }
}

Template Override
Override the layered navigation template to include your custom filter.
<!-- app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml -->
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Layer\View */
?>
<div class="block filter">
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
            <?php if ($filter->getName() == 'Your Custom Attribute'): ?>
                <div class="filter-item">
                    <strong class="filter-item-title"><?php echo $filter->getName(); ?></strong>
                    <ol class="items">
                        <?php foreach ($filter->getItems() as $item): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $item->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $item->getLabel(); ?></a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <!-- Default filter rendering -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>

Step 4: Refresh Cache and Reindex

Flush the cache: php bin/magento cache:flush
Reindex the data: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Step 5: Verify
Check your Category/Search pages and the layered navigation to ensure that the custom attribute filter appears and works correctly.
Additional Debugging
If the filter doesn't appear or doesn't work as expected, check the following:

Ensure the attribute is assigned to the products correctly.
Ensure the attribute is included in the product collection by checking your Layer model override.
Verify that the layered navigation template is being overridden correctly.

By following these steps, you should be able to add your custom attribute to the layered navigation and make it functional on the Category/Search pages.

Thank you for the answer. But as my question is: I want to add filter directly in product collection, NOT by clicking from the frontend. When layered navigation render and showing count, I want to filter that collection show the count shows with respect to collection.
